# Calling Close() on WCF client channel times out on Mono Mac but works on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mono

I have a WCF server running on Windows (.Net framework 4.8) using a NetTCP binding. I have both Windows and Mac clients. **The same code is used on both the Windows and Mac clients.**
The Windows client is running on .Net framework 4.8, the Mac client is running on Mono 6.12.0.122.

The client is very simple:

- Connect to the server
- Call a command on the server
- Close the connection to the server

It works fine on the Windows clients however on the Mac client the call to Close() always times out after 1 minute. Note: In both cases the server sees the disconnection immediately after it is sent from the client.

**Why does the call to Close() timeout on the Mac client even though it's the same code as the Windows client?**

Any advice why this is happening is greatly appreciated.

Client code:

```
ChannelFactory<IMyServerInterface> channelFactory;
internal IMyServerInterface channel;


internal MyConnection(string serverIPAddress, int serverPort)
{
    this.serverIPAddress = serverIPAddress;
    this.serverPort = serverPort;
    try
    {
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding
        {
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
            CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20),
            Security = new NetTcpSecurity
            {
                Mode = SecurityMode.None,
            },
        };
        InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress($"net.tcp://{serverIPAddress}:{serverPort}");
        channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyServerInterface>(instanceContext, binding, endpointAddress);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.File.Debug(ex, "WCF exception");
    }
}


internal void Connect()
{
    channel = channelFactory?.CreateChannel();

    ((IContextChannel)channel).Closed += (sender, e) => { OnConnectionLost("Connection closed", CommunicationState.Closed); };
    ((IContextChannel)channel).Faulted += (sender, e) => { OnConnectionLost("Connection faulted", CommunicationState.Faulted); };

    Log.File.Debug("Calling HandShake..");
    Result res = channel?.HandShake();
    if (res?.Success == true)
    {
        Log.File.Debug($"Connected to server at {serverIPAddress}:{serverPort}");
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Handshake to server failed" + (res == null? "": $": {res.Description}"));
    }
}


internal void CloseChannel()
{
    Log.File.Debug($"CloseChannel");
    var channelRef = (ICommunicationObject)channel;
    channel = null;

    if (channelRef != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.File.Debug($"CloseChannel: Calling Close() on channel");
            channelRef.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.File.Debug($"CloseChannel: {ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
            Log.File.Debug($"CloseChannel: Calling Abort() on channel");
            channelRef.Abort();
        }
    }
    Log.File.Debug($"CloseChannel finished");
}
```

My client has the behaviour:

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, AutomaticSessionShutdown = true)]
```

My service has the behaviour:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, AutomaticSessionShutdown = true, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true) ]
```

Calling MyConnection(), Connect(), CloseChannel() results in:

```
2021-07-16 12:30:10.9576 | Calling HandShake..
2021-07-16 12:30:11.6284 | Connected to server at 192.168.10.2:5154
2021-07-16 12:30:11.6644 | CloseChannel
2021-07-16 12:30:11.6648 | CloseChannel: Calling Close() on channel
2021-07-16 12:31:11.6746 | CloseChannel: System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.   <-- Why??!
2021-07-16 12:31:11.6762 | CloseChannel: Calling Abort() on channel
2021-07-16 12:31:11.6807 | OnConnectionLost: Connection closed
2021-07-16 12:31:11.6811 | CloseChannel  finished
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant but running Wireshark on both the Windows and Mac clients shows that when the connection is closed the Windows the client sends a TCP RST to the server whilst the Mac client sends FIN to the server (and the server replies with it's own FIN):

Windows:
[image]

Mac:
[image]

A secondary issue is that the following CloseTimeout setting is not being applied (it times out after the default of 1 minute):

```
CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)
```

However it does get applied if I set it in the argument to Close() i.e. changing:

```
channelRef.Close();
```

To:

```
channelRef.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running on the latest version of Mono to see if there are any problems.

If this fails,I suggest you upload a complete bug record of the test to: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Jiayao. I created a bug report at: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/21163
together with a simple sample project that shows the problem (the same code running on MacOS hangs when calling Close() on the channel).

Comment: If anyone looking at this thread wants to take a look at the sample project on the github link, I'd appreciate any feedback. However, I can only think that it's a bug in Mono.

Comment: I agree with you and thank you for your comment.